# *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] when selecting the back button

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

Getting this error when i hit back in either view controller or tableview controllers.

Back is a bar button item on a navigation bar that is segued back to the previous controller or my main directory tableviewcontroller.  No code is used with this bar button item.

My information is stored on parse (if that is of any importance)

My tableview is not inserting or deleting anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you create the barbuttonitem? If so, you have segued it wrong somehow. Just delete the back barbuttonitem, and navigationController will create it for you automatically (at run time).

Comment: How do i get it to show if i don't create one?  I deleted it and ran the app but no back button appears.

Comment: If you have a segue from the main view controller to the second view controller then when the second view controller is pushed it should have a back button on the navigation controller. And when pressed it simply pops back.

Comment: ok i don't have a navigation controller.  I have table view controllers and view controllers both with navigation bars.

Comment: I have added a navigation controller to see if that fixes the problem., will update soon

Comment: It doesn't happen as often but it still happens.  This time i noticed it happening when i selected one  of the options in my table view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a view controller or table view controller rather than a navigation controller.  I changed it so i was using a navigation controller.  I then selected my view controller and selected editor / embed in / navigation controller.  It seems to work for the most part.